# Binding const reference to another type

Tags: c++, const-reference

How to know if you can bind a `const` reference `T1` to `T2` ?

I used to think that you can bind `const` reference `T1` to type `T2` only if `T2` is convertible to `T1`.
But since the following compiles:

```
char x[10];
const char (&y)[10] = x;
```

that should not be the case, since `char[10]` is not convertible to `const char[10]` (correct me if I'm wrong). So, what are the rules for being able to bind `const` references to different types ? Is there just an additional rule like: *for any type `T` you can bind a `const` reference `T` to it* ?

Comment: *"`char[10]` is not convertible to `const char[10]`"*  why shouldn't it be? You can always add `const` to any type

Comment: You can always add const to a non-const whatever.

Comment: _"for any type T you can bind a const reference to it ?"_ Why not? Vice-versa you'll get into troubles, but that way no harm is done.

Comment: @UnholySheep I've used std::convertible_to concept (C++20 thing) to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard describes the reference binding rules in [[dcl.init.ref]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#4) and [[dcl.init.ref]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5). There is a rather long list of rules, but the bits most relevant to your question are:

[[dcl.init.ref]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#4):

> Given types “cv1 T1” and “cv2 T2”, “cv1 T1” is reference-related to “cv2 T2” if T1 is similar ([conv.qual]) to T2, or T1 is a base class of T2.
> “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2” if a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 T2” can be converted to the type “pointer to cv1 T1” via a standard conversion sequence ([conv]).

[[dcl.init.ref]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5):

> A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> — If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>     — is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”, or
>     [...]
> then the reference binds to the initializer expression lvalue [...]

In your case, `T1` would be `const char [10]` and `T2` would be `char [10]`. `T1` is *reference-compatible* with `T2` because `T2*` can be converted to `T1*`, as it only requires adding `const`-qualification to the pointed type, which is a standard conversion.

As you can see in the referenced sections, this is not the only case where reference binding is allowed - another case, for example, is binding a reference to a result of conversion (including user-defined). `const` references are also special as they are allowed to bind to rvalues.

Note that this is indeed different from your previous understanding - `T2` may not be convertible to `T1` while you may be able to bind a reference still. Here's an example:

```
struct A
{
    A(int);
    A(A const&) = delete;
};

struct B : A
{
    B() : A(10) {}
};

B b;
A& ra = b; // ok, binds to base subobject A of b
A a = b;   // fail, A cannot be constructed from an object of B
```